# operator new already defined in custom memory manager with library

Tags: c++, memory, stl

Sorry for the poor title, but hopefully the description makes it clearer.

At the momemnt I have one main application which is built together with other libraries (like libpng, libvorbis,etc.). I'm trying to add libtheoraplayer to the main application, but I keep running into problems:

1) Linking to a pre-built library of llibtheoraplayer and including the appropriate header files gives me an error saying that pushMemoryManager cannot be found (part of our custom memory manager)

2) Building the library together with the main application results in a linker error "error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,void *)" (??2@YAPAXIPAX@Z) already defined in win32Mem.obj"

I'm not quite sure where to start debugging this. The main application does not support STL, and I started by changing references to STL in the libtheoraplayer to our own STL replacements, but I'm still getting error 2 as above after finding the offending files and changing them.

Any wild ideas?

Comment: Replacing standard library (if only STL part) is silly, unless you have a damn good reason.

Comment: There is a damn good reason to replace STL. Older versions of Microsoft STL sucked big time and some components of their STL still do. However, replacing their allocator is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silence the linker error (convert to warning) with `/FORCE` and pray that there are no cross-library allocations ending up using different allocators.

It's rather difficult to replace allocation functions on Windows (NT or CE), because:

1. Dynamic symbols are loaded from specific libraries, so you will replace which allocator is used in your code, but not which is used in libraries you link dynamically. If you don't link dynamically and silence the linker error with `/FORCE`, it will do the right thing and override the allocators from standard library just fine.

   With dynamic linking if code living in one library allocates and code living in another library frees, there will be mismatch in allocators used and thus probably crash. Unfortunately it may easily happen even if both functions are defined by the same library, but one of them is a template (so the instance lives in the library refering to it) and the other is not (so it lives in the library defining it).
2. They have some non-standard entry points to the allocator and sometimes use them from other code. We used to use [duma](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) library and actually managed to override both C (malloc/realloc/free) and C++ (operator new and operator delete) allocators, but hit a wall when we started using iostreams, where they allocate with the standard function, but free with something like `__debug_free` or the other way 'round.

On a side-note, the same is absolutely trivial on Linux, because in GNU libc malloc, realloc and free call the real allocator through pointers that you can easily override (operator new and operator delete just call malloc and free respectively basically everywhere).

Comment: Thanks for your insight, but we decided to manually comb through the source and replace std::list, std::map and std::vector with our own replacements :(